# Convert latitude/longitude to carto geo points

Tags: carto, geometry

I have a pandas df in databricks, with two column latitude and longitude, and I want to convert them to geom points in order to conduct the whitespace analysis. How can I use carto Python API do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using GeoPandas to create a GeoDataFrame that [can be pushed into CARTO](https://carto.com/developers/cartoframes/examples/#example-upload-to-carto) to populate the `the_geom` column from your Pandas DataFrame using the `points_from_xy` function (see https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html)

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df['longitude'], df.['latitude']))
```

Another option would be to upload the DataFrame into CARTO, then populate the `the_geom` column through a SQL query using PostGIS [ST_Point](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) function (if the dataset is large you could use the [Batch API](https://carto.com/developers/sql-api/guides/batch-queries/) for this, or CARTOframes SQLClient's execute method, which uses Batch queries behind the scenes).

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET the_geom = ST_Point(longitude, latitude)
```